# Parallelizing insert queries that operate on large volume of data in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, parallel-processing, bigdata

I have the following query that I would like to cut into smaller queries
and execute in parallel:

```
insert into users (
SELECT user, company, date
FROM (
  SELECT
    json_each(json ->> 'users') user
    json ->> 'company' company,
    date(datetime) date
  FROM companies
  WHERE date(datetime) = '2015-05-18'
 ) AS s
);
```

I could try to do it manually - launch workers that would connect to Postgresql
and every worker would take 1000 companies, extract users and insert to the other table. But is it possible to do it in plain SQL?